# Foursquare-api-java doesn't work

Tags: foursquare

i want to retrieve an information of checkin with this library, but i have an error in the response.

This is my code:

```
FoursquareApi foursquareApi = new FoursquareApi("Client ID", "Client Secret", "Callback URL");
Result<Checkin> result;
    try {

    result = foursquareApi.checkin("id_checkin", "signature");

        if (result.getMeta().getCode() == 200) {
            Checkin checkin = result.getResult();
}
```

But i have this error:

```
Error occured: 
code: 401
type: invalid_auth
detail: OAuth token invalid or revoked.
```

if I use the same codes in the explorer foursquare utility works.
why I have this problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source for this call](https://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/fi/foyt/foursquare/api/FoursquareApi.java?spec=svn313&r=312#1115), it looks like the author of the library has set `auth=true`, which matches what the [Foursquare API Documentation for the endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins) says is required.

The VenuesExplore call, though, doesn't default auth to true, meaning that it will, appropriately, not send along an auth token if you haven't logged in.

So, what you need to do to get your checkin call working is to have your user go through the authentication process and get a valid OAuth token for them. That way, the checkin call will no longer fail since it will send along a valid OAuth token, allowing Foursquare to properly check your user's permission to view a given check-in.